# how to delete external site cookies through C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I have a authentication page for windows azure authentication where authentication is performed on https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=........
and after successful authentication we are redirecting to our site.

We need to delete cookies generated on this url for logout. can any body provide me the code through which we can delete external site cookies.

We have tried to delete using the following code but could not get success.

```
public void deleteallcookies()
{
    int limit = Request.Cookies.Count; 
    HttpCookie aCookie;   //Instantiate a cookie placeholder
    string cookieName;   

    //Loop through the cookies
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;    //get the name of the current cookie
        aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);    
         aCookie.Value = "";    //set a blank value to the cookie 
        aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);    

        Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);    //Set the cookie
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the cookie from the Response not the Request, i.e.

```
cookieName = Response.Cookies[i].Name;
```

you can also enumerate slightly more elegantly as follows:

```
string[] myCookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
foreach (string cookieName in myCookies)
{
      var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieName];
      if (cookie != null)
      {
            cookie.Value = "";
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
      }
}
```

Comment: above code also not work to delete external site cookies through this code we are able to delete our site cookies only.

Comment: wouldn't think you'd be allowed to delete cookies that are not from your domain

Comment: is it possible to delete cookies that are not from our domain?

Comment: think about it, it would be a pretty wide security loop hole